# Computing Arctan2 with 1 argument in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, math, trigonometry

I have a DF whereby I need to compute the arctan of two north/south wind components. However, it seems that the arctan2 function only takes 2 arguments x,y such according to the documentation:

```
numpy.arctan2(x1, x2, /, out=None, *, where=True, casting='same_kind', order='K', dtype=None, subok=True[, signature, extobj]) = <ufunc 'arctan2'>
```

However, I need to divide the x, y components to obtain my desired answer. So, I need to do this -

dfout = np.arctan2(x/y) using 1 argument but the documentation says that I need 2 arguments x,y.

I see the "/" symbol as an option but I'm not sure if that applies or how to do that. Any ideas?

My data looks like this in df:

```
day hour    Cns       Cew
1   0       126.002   -100.812
1   1      -42.3775    18.6631
1   2       64.3313   -121.167
```

I need to do this in the example above:

```
dfout = np.arctan2(df.Cew/df.Cns)
```

but I get this error -

```
TypeError: arctan2() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 1 were given
```

I have tried this but I get a syntax error.

```
dfout = np.arctan2(df.Cew,df.Cns,/)
```

Using this below does not provide the correct answer as I am trying to compute the average wind direction using the Cew (EAST-WEST) and Cns (NORTH-SOUTH) components of the wind.

This will NOT work -

dfout = np.arctan2(Cew, Cns).

And, my angles range from -180 to + 180 wind direction angles in degrees.

thanks much,

Comment: The `/` in the documentation only serves to indicate the role of parameters as *positional* / *keyword*. You can safely ignore it for now, but if you want to know about them more precisely, please look at https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/#specification

Comment: Can you explain **how** it does not work?

Comment: Have you tried `np.arctan2(df.Cns, df.Cew)` ?

Answer (score 1):

The function that takes 1 argument is called `np.arctan`. But I am not sure you really need it.

```py
np.arctan(-100.812/126.002)
# -0.6747912684731013
np.arctan2(-100.812, 126.002)
# -0.6747912684731013
```

So, you see... why would you want to do the division yourself, rather than letting `np.arctan2` do it?

Plus, `np.arctan2` is better. Because `np.arctan` can't know the exact angle, since one information is missing. That information being the direction.

Think of a 45° angle. `np.arctan(1/1)` = π/4. As expected. And, obviously, so is `np.arctan2(1,1)`.
But, what if coordinates are (-1,-1)? `np.arctan(-1/-1)` is also π/4 (obvioulsly: -1/-1=1/1=1). But (-1,-1) angle is not at 45°, but the opposite direction, that is 5π/4 (or -3π/4).

```py
np.arctan(1/1)
# 0.7853981633974483
np.arctan2(1,1)
# 0.7853981633974483
np.arctan(-1/-1)
# 0.7853981633974483
np.arctan2(-1,-1)
# -2.356194490192345
```

Usually, people want the angle computed from (-1,-1) to be -3π/4, not π/4.

You have such a case in your sample data

```py
np.arctan(18.6631/-42.3775)
# -0.41484291425043723
np.arctan2(18.6631,-42.3775)
# 2.726749739339356
```

The second one (unless I am missing something from a specificity of your application) is better. You expect (-42.3775, 18.6631) to be somewhere in the second quadrant, that is between π/2 and π. As arctan2 says. But arctan place it in the fourth.

So in your case

```py
# Either
dfout = np.arctan2(df.Cew, df.Cns)
# Or
dfout = np.arctan(df.Cew/df.Cns)
```

But the first one is probably what you want.

Last remark: arguments of `arctan2` are not x and y, but y and x. Likewise, what you should call `arctan` with is not x/y but y/x. Since I don't know what your `Cew` and `Cns` exactly are, I let it as is. But I surmise it means "east-west", and "north-south", so you may want to replace by

```
dfout = np.arctan2(df.Cns, df.Cew)
# Or
dfout = np.arctan(df.Cns/df.Cew)
```

But that is not a coding problem, more a math problem (what do you want to compute arctan of), so I let it up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use:

```
dfout = np.arctan2(df.Cew, df.Cns)
```

(or swapping the inputs `np.arctan2(df.Cns, df.Cew)` -- it is not clear from the question itself, but you should be able to get around that from the documentation and what you know about your input).

---

The [`np.arctan2()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) implements [`atan2(y, x)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2), which is meant to solve the ambiguity resulting from the sign combination in the `y / x` parameter of `arctan(y / x)`, thus **requiring** the two arguments.

If you do not need to resolve that ambiguity, you can safely use [`np.arctan()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan.html), which only uses one argument -- `y / x`.